# email working local but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I'm trying to send out an email after a button click event. When testing from my local machine everything runs smooth, the email get send out and I get the popup message notifying me that the "call has been resolved". But running from server side the page "hangs" - the screen is dimmed out which should happen until the email is sent off, but it stays like that. the email does not get sent out from server side....

This is what I've done:
My code:

```
    MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();
        Mail.Subject = "Call Resolved";
        Mail.To.Add(useremail);
        //  Mail.To.Add(useremail);
        Mail.From = new MailAddress("notifications@oep.co.za");

        // string path = Server.MapPath(@"..\Images\SOSLetterhead.png");
        // string path = PopulateEmailImage();
        string path = Server.MapPath(@"\Images\ItsmBCXHeader.gif");
        LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(path);
        logo.ContentId = "header";

        AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><head>" +
                            @"<meta content=""text/html; charset=utf-8"" http-equiv=""Content-Type""/> " +
                            @"<title></title></head><body ><style> " +
                        @".auto-style1 {width: 188px; }table tr td{ border:solid;border-width:1px;} .link{color:red;}</style> " +
                        @"<img alt="""" height=""130"" src=""cid:header"" width=""675"" /> " +
                        @"<div style=""color:red; font-weight:bold; text-align:left; border:none; margin-right:20%;"" > " +
                        @"<h3>This message is sent on behalf of <br /> The Business Connexion Global Service Management Centre</h3> " +
                        @"<h5><i>Please do not respond to the sender as this mailbox does not receive return mail. <br /> " +
                        @"Use the Link located at the bottom of the e-mail to Respond </i></h5> </div><br />" +
                        @"<div>Dear <b>" + CustName + "</b></div><br /> " +
                        @"<div>We are pleased to inform you that your reported Incident <b>" + incidentNo + "</b>, has been resolved. </div><br /> " +
                        @"<div><b>Incident Summary report as follows:</b></div> <br /> " +
                        @"<table style=""width:45%; border:solid; border-width:3px; background-color:#E2E2E2;""> " +
                        @"<tr><td class=""auto-style1""><b>Incident Number:</b></td><td>" + incidentNo + "</td> " +
                        @"<tr><td class=""auto-style1""><b>Status:</b></td><td>" + stats + "</td></tr> " +
                        @"<tr><td class=""auto-style1""><b>CI Serial No:</b></td><td>" + serialNo + "</td></tr> " +
                        @"<tr><td class=""auto-style1""><b>Incident Summary:</b></td><td>" + incidentSum + "</td></tr> " +
                        @"<tr><td class=""auto-style1""><b>Incident Notes:</b></td><td>" + incidentNotes + "</td></tr> " +
                        @"<tr><td class=""auto-style1""><b>Resolution:</b></td><td>" + resolution + "</td></tr> " +
                        @"</table><br /><div> " +
                        @"If you have any queries or if you would like to change your contact details, please contact the <br /> Global Service Management Centre. " +
                        @"</div><br /><div> " +
                        @"<a href=""spoc@bcx.co.za"" class=""link"">Click here if you would like to contact the Global Service Management Centre via e-mail</a> </div> " +
                        @"<br /><div><b>011 266 1102</b> (National, South African number) <br /><b>+27 (0) 266 1102</b> (International number)<br /> " +
                        @"E-mail queries to <a href=""spoc@bcx.co.za"" class=""link"">spoc@bcx.co.za</a> <br /></div><br /><div><b>Yours in service <br /> " +
                        @"Global Service Management Centre</b></div></body></html>", null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

        av1.LinkedResources.Add(logo);
        Mail.AlternateViews.Add(av1);

        System.Configuration.Configuration configurationFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");
        MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings = configurationFile.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
        if (mailSettings != null)
        {
            int port = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port;
            string host = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host;
            string password = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password;
            string username = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName;
        }
        SmtpClient SMTP = new SmtpClient();
        SMTP.Send(Mail);
```

And my web.config:

```
    <mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Notifications@smart-office.co.za">
    <network host="host" userName="notifications@oep.co.za" password="password" port="25" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

I have removed the password and host for security reasons... Any help will be greatly appreciated! this works on another site, but not on this one.....

Comment: From the server you have deployed to, can you telnet into the mailserver to check it's listening on the expected port?

Comment: @mwrichardson, yes I am able to connect via telnet... Everything looks ok there... Thanks for your reply!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had once this problem, I changed the value of `EnableSsl` field of `SmtpClient` to `false` before publishing and it worked for me, If you already have false then change it to `true`

Comment: adding EnableSsl gives me errors on both true and false, true gives error on local and server, but the false only on the server...

Comment: get thet value from web.config file, use different values on client and server

Comment: Could you behind a restricted network locally? if enablessl works on the server it should work locally also.

Comment: enablessl does not work on the server at all, neither true nor false... only false works on local...

Answer (score 0):

Check in windows Event viewer for more details. it might log information if its problem with environment.